# Why aren't the numbers from my input file going into my array c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I am passing a text file of integers to a function by reference. They are separated by a new line. I am wanting to push them into a new array in the function. I can count the number of lines no problem, and I use that variable to create the array of that given size, so a vector is not necessary. But when I print what should be the contents of my array it is way off. Do I need to convert the integers from the file into int values again (since I am reading from a text file, is it reading them as strings?) Help?

C++ Code:

```
void myFunction(ifstream& infile)
{
    int NumberOfLines = 0;
    int index;
    string line;
    //Count the number of lines in the file
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(infile, line))
        {
            ++NumberOfLines;
        }
    }
    int arr[NumberOfLines];
    //Put the numbers into an array
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile>>arr[NumberOfLines];
    }
    //Print the array
    for(int i=0; i<NumberOfLines; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I use that variable to create the array of that given size" This is actually illegal in C++. It is allowed by extension by some C++ compilers, but it's use is not recommended. A) doesn't work with all compilers. B) It's a really easy way to overflow your stack (or whatever is used for automatic storage) 3) It makes an absolute horrorshow out of the `sizeof` operator. Use the `vector`. This sort of thing is exactly what it is for.

Comment: `while(!infile.eof())` is a common bug. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: `infile>>arr[NumberOfLines];` writes out of bounds (even if the compiler supports this array, the lat valid index is `NumberOfLines-1`

Answer (score 1):

When you first scan the file, in order to count the lines, the `ifstream` position indicator reaches the end of the file.

In order to read the file again, you should reset the position indicator to the beginning, using:

`infile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);`

More info: [seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: Note: You may also need to `clear()` the eof flag before rewinding the file.

Comment: @user4581301 you're right in case he doesn't use c++11 or later. Since c++11 `seekg` does it for you.

Comment: Son of a gun. Didn't know that, but there it is in **[istream.unformatted]**. Very cool.